# How can I skip the first line of a csv in Java?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I want to skip the first line and use the second as header.

I am using classes from apache commons csv to process a CSV file.

The header of the CSV file is in the second row, not the first (which contains coordinates).

My code looks like this:

```
static void processFile(final File file) {
    FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
    final CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';');
    CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(filereader, format);
    final List<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();
    //stuff
}
```

I naively thought,

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withDelimiter(;)
```

would solve the problem, as it's different from withFirstRowAsHeader and I thought it would detect that the first row doesn't contain any semicolons and is not a record. It doesn't. I tried to skip the first line (that CSVFormat seems to think is the header) with

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withSkipHeaderRecord().withFirstRecordAsHeader().withDelimiter(;);
```

but that also doesn't work. What can I do?  What's the difference between withFirstRowAsHeader and withFirstRecordAsHeader?

Comment: Have you tried reading until newLine before giving the fileReader to the parser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to read the first line, before passing the reader to the `CSVParser` :

```
static void processFile(final File file) {
    FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
    bufferedReader.readLine();// try-catch omitted
    final CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';');
    CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(bufferedReader, format);
    final List<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: In case of my `,` seperated csv file, I need to change `CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';');` to `CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(',');`. Is this correct?

Comment: readLine ? What if the first record contains "bla\r\nbli".

Answer (score 31):

The correct way to skip the first line if it is a header is by using a different `CSVFormat`

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';').withFirstRecordAsHeader();
```

**Update: June 30 2022**

For 1.9+, use

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder()                                                                  
    .setDelimiter(';')
    .setHeader()
    .setSkipHeaderRecord(true)  // skip header
    .build();
```

Comment: +1 for withFirstRecordAsHeader(), I use it with CSVParser and it skips the header when you iterate  over the parser.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it uses the library, instead of an ad-hoc pure Java solution

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: I think the original question was about the first *two* lines, where the second contains the header.

Comment: for me it currently shows withDelimiter as deprecated.

Comment: I think the setHeader() method must be call too:
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder()                                                                  
    .setDelimiter(';').setHeader()
    .setSkipHeaderRecord(true)  // skip header
    .build();

Comment: setHeader() will read the first record as the headers. The question says the headers are in the second record.

Answer (score 6):

In version 1.9.0 of org.apache.commons:commons-csv use:

```
val format = CSVFormat.Builder.create(CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
        .setHeader()
        .setSkipHeaderRecord(true)
        .build()

val parser = CSVParser.parse(reader, format)
```

Comment: Or: `CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder()...`.

Comment: The headers are in the second record.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the first record using stream:

```
List<CSVRecord> noHeadersLine = records.stream.skip(1).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your file format looks something like:

```
<garbage line here>
<header data>
<record data starts here>
```

For version 1.9.0, use, as given above, but with one addition:

```
Reader in = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.Builder.create(CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
            .setHeader()
            .setSkipHeaderRecord(true)
            .build();
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(bufferedReader, format);
for (CSVRecord record : parser.getRecords()) {
    <do something>
}
```

If you don't skip that first line somehow, you will throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: readLine ? What if a column contains CR LF ?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it using Java Streams:

```
parser.getRecords().stream()
     .filter(record -> record.getRecordNumber() != 1) 
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? What's that `csvRecordToPayerCodeMapping` needed for?

Comment: Sorry that is for internal use, you can skip .map(). Will edit the same

Answer (score 0):

You could consume the first line and then pass it to the CSVParser. Other than that there is a method [#withIgnoreEmptyLines](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withIgnoreEmptyLines-boolean-) which might solve the issue.

Comment: the problem is the line isn't empty. But using BufferedReader (which has a readLine method) solved it.

Answer (score 0):

the .setHeader() method must be call for the .setSkipHeaderRecord(true)  to take effect.

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder()                                                                  
    .setDelimiter(';')
    .setHeader()    
    .setSkipHeaderRecord(true)  // skip header
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your first record doesn't contain CR LF characters, you can use the "readLine" method. Otherwise you have to read twice.

First get the headers :

```
CSVFormat format;
List<String> headers = null;
try(Reader reader = getReader()) {
  Iterator<CSVRecord> iter = format.parse(reader).iterator();
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();
  if(iter.hasNext()) {
    headers = iter.next().toList();
  }
}
```

Then read again :

```
try(Reader reader = getReader()) {
  format = format.builder().setHeader(headers.toArray(new String[0])).build();
  Iterator<CSVRecord> iter = format.parse(reader).iterator();
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    CSVRecord record = iter.next();
    //do stuff
  }
}
```